# Convert Single Gang to Dual Gang for Ceiling Light/Fan Fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I’m resurrecting a question I asked a couple months back, but now I have pictures that should hopefully help illustrate what I’m asking. Thank you for the preliminary responses, hopefully now this will make more sense.

This is to control a bedroom ceiling fan/light fixture. This was originally a single gang box with one switch that controlled both the fan and light. I'm trying to convert this into a dual gang box with one switch for the light and one switch for the fan. I believe (although I am not 100% sure) that the original single gang set up had all three neutrals nutted together and all three hots nutted together with a pigtail that went to the switch.

There are three sets of wires in the box. The hot from the bottom is the feed, and I'm assuming the top two sets of wires go to the fixture. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? I tried pigtailing two new pieces of cable to the hot feed to create two "hots", one to each switch, but all I end up with is one switch that still controls both light and fan and then a second switch that does nothing.

And yes, I know I didn't do a great job fitting the box into the little opening I had in the wall. The wall plate I have will cover this so I'm not freaking out!

[image: Three sets of wires, hot on bottom is the feed]

Comment: You should confirm your assumption that two sets of wires to go the ceiling box. Often there is an extra wire in boxes that goes on to power an unrelated part of the circuit. I bet the smarter-than-me people that can give you a better answer would also appreciate a picture of the ceiling box and wiring.

Comment: _I believe (although I am not 100% sure) that the original single gang set up had [...] all three hots nutted together with a pigtail that went to the switch._  So what was connected to the other side of the switch?  My guess is that you remember incorrectly and that _two_ of the hots were connected together and pigtailed to one switch terminal, and the third was connected to the other switch terminal.  In that case you're likely out of luck unless you have an attic above there or want to tear open your ceiling to run a new 3-conductor cable.

Comment: With the age of the wiring do not assume anything! Open the ceiling box and verify the wiring. Actually verify the wires are what you are guessing. It is a simple task verify no connection then short the 2 wires together and now there should be a connection, do this with each cable. It was not as common to run an extra wire for a fan but it could have been done.

Comment: I agree with @izzy.  You need to confirm where those wires go. Get a continuity tester and ring them out.